# Gray bars when scrolling

Tags: nautilus, gedit

I've been reinstalling things like the text editor and the file manager, and now I get these gray bars when scrolling to the edge.

[image: gray bars above]![enter image description here]

Comment: Does this show in screenshots, and what graphics (and other hardware) are you using?

Comment: I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

It's the scrolling animation. Nautilus and gedit now include an effect for when you scroll. If, however, your GTK theme isn't compatible with those animations, that happens. Just update your theme or switch it for another.